# Click on notification doesn't start a specific activity

Tags: android, notifications, action

I am using a notification where I added an "action" which should start an activity.

I have two main activities: Login Activity and MainActivity. When the LoginActivity is started, it automatically logs in the user (if the user was previously logged in), does some other stuff, and then starts MainActivity.
MainActivity is the host for several fragments.

Now when I add LoginActivity like this:

```
 Intent notificationIntent;
 notificationIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);

 notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
         Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
 PendingIntent intentp =
         PendingIntent.getActivity(getActivity(), 0, notificationIntent, 0);            

    NotificationCompat.Builder nBuilder;
    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager
            .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    nBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getActivity())
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Smart Share - " + "")
            .setLights(Color.BLUE, 500, 500).setContentText("message")
            .setAutoCancel(true).setTicker("Notification from smartshare")
            .setVibrate(new long[] { 100, 250, 100, 250, 100, 250 })
            .setSound(alarmSound)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(intentp);
    NotificationManager nNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) getActivity()
            .getSystemService(getActivity().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
   Notification not = nBuilder.build();
   nNotifyMgr.notify(2 + 2, not);
```

Everything works fine. When I put MainActivity into the notificationIntent, a click on the notification does nothing.

How come?

**EDIT:**

Snippets from my manifest file:

```
  <activity
        android:name="<packagename>.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" >
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>  
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="<packagename>.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/tab_title_mapview" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
```

Comment: Can you share your manifest file?

Comment: u miss    mManager.notify(100, notification); see my answer

Comment: Or post you all code.

Comment: Your `mainActivity` belong to the same Package? and try this `nNotifyMgr.notify(1, not);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getActivity(),0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT| PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

Comment: afaik that's not necessary since I am using '.setContentIntent(intentp);' inside the builder.

Comment: If not so then what's your exact problem.

Comment: When I put LoginActivity inside the PendingIntent, this Activity starts just fine. When I put MainActivity inside the PendingIntent, a click on the notification only makes the notification disappear (which it should), but doesn't start the desired activity.

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked!
Do you also know how I can resume an activity if it's in the background?

Answer (score 3):

try with this dude actually u miss **mManager.notify(100, notification);**

```
NotificationManager mManager = (NotificationManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Tittle", System.currentTimeMillis());
                RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getBaseContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.customnotification_alert);
                contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.progressBar, 10, 0, false);        
                contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.text, "text ");       
                notification.contentView = contentView;

                Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), NotifyMessage.class);
                PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 0, notificationIntent, 0);
                notification.contentIntent = contentIntent;
                mManager.notify(100, notification);
```

Comment: Is that any reason to added `RemoteViews` ?

Comment: he miss mManager.notify(100, notification); see my answer

Comment: @Bhanu Sharma I posted the entire code I used for creating a notification, I didn't miss .notify, I just didn't post it originally. :)

Comment: try with notification.setLatestEventInfo

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);
 notificationIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), LoginActivity.class);
 notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
     Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
 PendingIntent intentp =
       PendingIntent.getActivity(getActivity(), 0, notificationIntent, 0);

notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, notificationIntent );
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, I solved it by doing to following:

Add this to your manifest (inside the activity tag)

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

And set the following flags to the intent you want to start:

```
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't help :(